# Spam?? Huh?? What triggers this lovely popup message?

Tags: discussion, support

I tried to post an answer to a question just now, a response/answer that has consumed a good bit of time and when I attempt to submit the response, I get a lovely little popup flag that says, "This looks like spam."

Okay...  It "looks" like spam, but it *isn't* spam.  How do I get around this?  What's the trigger that causes this flag?

Comment: can you quote the text of the answer you tried to post in the question here?

Comment: Jack, that's an interesting proposal.  It's fairly lengthy (which may be the issue), but I'll try it.

Comment: Aha!!  There's the problem.  This site (meta) gives me a message that the Biblical Hermeneutics site does not give.  There is a maxlength attribute tied to the messages. The error message (here) did not say what that maxlength is, but that my message of #### characters exceeded the limit.

bummer...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the patterns are, but I know the limitations on adding links for brand new users are much tighter than they are for those of us that have been around and posted a few other answers. Can you save a copy of your content locally and try posting a version without links? If that works we can help you edit them in after the initial post.

If not, try editing at least a sample of it into your question here an meta and maybe that will give us a clue what the problem is.

Comment: Caleb,  thank you for the kind response.  No links in the post, but troubleshooting with Jack above, I see that the posting exceeds the allowed length limit.  I believe I could break it into two posts and handle it that way.

Comment: That assumes that length limitations are the same across all StackExchange sites.

Comment: @DJGray To my knowledge they are, but it again as a first time poster the spam filters are on high alert so it might be tightening up on things that aren't normal usage patterns. I've never heard of anybody hitting the character limit with their first post except when trying to copy/paste their thesis in toto onto unrelated questions rather that quoting the relevant bits.

Comment: That makes sense, Caleb.  Thanks for the great feedback.  I will just need to lurk in the shadows a bit and build enough reputation.  There are some fascinating discussions going on, and I can enjoy my time reading.  :-)